# is it possible to run blackberry OS 10 in blackberry OS 6,7 and 7.1

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-jde, blackberry-webworks

I am new to blackberry development; please let me know **is it possible to run blackberry OS 10 apps on blackberry OS 6,7 and 7.1**?  Or *vice versa*?

Also i want know how to develop a flip board type application for blackberry OS 10, or OS 6 and 7.

Comment: do you mean `BB 10 app` in os6,7?

Comment: yes BB 10 App in OS 6,7..as well as is it possible to run OS 6 and 7 app in BB 10 OS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BB OS 10 and BB OS 7,6,5 are not compatible. Thers is no such thing like binary code compatibility between BB 10 and BB RIM OS 7.x and older devices.

But there's a workaround. Use [HTML5/WebWorks](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/) to implement an application and compile it for every platform. In this case this application will work on BB 10 and will work on legacy RIM OS devices (7.x, 6.0, 5.0).

**update:**

There are two WebWorks editions. One for [BlackBerry OS](http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/html5/download/), another for [BB 10 OS](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/).

Comment: that is to say if i download the webworks 2.0 sdk , i can write apps for both older and newer versions blackberry ?

Comment: @UDcreate There are two WebWorks editions. One for [BlackBerry OS](http://developer.blackberry.com/bbos/html5/download/), another for [BB 10 OS](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/).