# Blackberry plugin for eclipse compatible with Blackberry 10

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

This may be an incredibly stupid question, but I have not gotten a clear answer through google. Will the eclipse Blackberry plugin work for the new Blackberry as well as older versions? I am actually an android developer so this is quite a change for me. Any hint will be appreciated. Thanx

**EDIT** `You can use the BlackBerry Runtime for Android apps to run Android Jelly Bean 4.2.2 (10.2) platform applications on the BlackBerry 10 OS. If you are developing for a previous version of BlackBerry 10 OS, use Android Gingerbread 2.3.3. To use the runtime, you must first repackage your Android applications to BAR file format, which is the compatible file format required for an application to run on the BlackBerry 10 OS.`

Got this from [here](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/mastertopic_1849583_11.html). Does this mean that I should write two apps? One for the old blackberry devices and one for the new one?

Comment: What are you asking about?  The **tools** used to build apps for legacy BB vs. BB 10?  Or the underlying language / libraries / platforms?  When, you say *older versions*, are you talking about initial releases of BB 10, or BB 5/6/7?

Comment: @Nate Sorry for being unclear. I'm talking about BB 5/6/7

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to run blackberry OS 10 in blackberry OS 6,7 and 7.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986932/is-it-possible-to-run-blackberry-os-10-in-blackberry-os-6-7-and-7-1). answer: yes, unless you want to use HTML5.

Comment: @Nate I guess you meant the answer is NO unless you use HTML5.

Comment: @MisterSmith, the question was actually posed two ways.  I was responding to the second one: *"do i need to write two apps"* so my answer is "yes", unless you use HTML5, in which case you can write one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that the above is clear, so thought I would restate the position as I understand it:

Android applications, repackaged to run on BlackBerry devices, can be used on BB10 and PlayBook devices only.  These can not be run on BBOS devices, i.e. BB 5/6/7.

The later releases of BB10, specifically 10.2+, supports Android applications developed using Jelly Bean 4.2.2.

PlayBook and previous levels of BB10, support Gingerbread 2.3.3.

So for example, my Z10, which is running BB10.1, would only be able to load repackaged Android applications developed using Gingerbread.  My Curve, running OS 7.0, can't run any Android applications.